# make more commit in same branch git

Tags: git, github

How to create more than commit to the same branch. I have a branch called branch_1 when I created it committed it with $ git commit -m "new message1".
my question that I make changes in my project and I want to create another commit with these changes.
**note that:-**
I don't want to override the previous commit so that branch_1 has 2 commits.
**clearly**
branch_1  has 2 commits or more
commit_1  "new message1"
commit_2  "new message2"
.
.
.
how to do that if it possible?

Comment: What is the problem with just doing `git add` to the changed files followed by making your second commit?

Comment: If you want to make a new commit without any changes, you can use `git commit --allow-emtpy`.

Comment: What do you mean by "override the previous commit"?

Comment: I want to add a secondary commit with the last changes to a specific branch. TimBiegeleisen can you give me completed commands to do another commit.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Biegeleisen he just got confused about what git branch does. That is it all. Am I right @Ali_ahmed?

Comment: yes, this is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you create a new branch and you `checkout` to this branch. All the commits you will do will go to this specific branch.

Whenever you want to commit a specif branch. Just use `git checkout branch_name`. And just commit here.

Another thing you should know is once you create a new branch all the previous changes in the other branch will be erased for this new branch ok. Do not worry they are saved in the repository.

So this does not mean that you have been overridden the previous commits ok. IF you want to merge all the commit just use `git merge` to merge all your changes once you finish working on your current branch ok.

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58881295/after-commit-git-files-and-folder-disappear-after-checkout/58884161#58884161) to remove your confusion :).

Comment: Do not worry. Every time you learn new things you got a lot of confusion. Just keep learning and that confusion will disappear :).